# how to get Complete Visible item postion from Listview with base adapter

Tags: android, listview

Listview have image and video and not both are in same item ,Here issues is If listview item contain video then make auto play that video,Now auto play completed based on adapter position but video played before view come in centre position,How to get Complete visible item position from device using listview [image] , see the screen show how to take position of 1 ,I mean center position of device, without **onClick()**

Comment: Does your ListView only show one item at a time? Have you considered what would happen on a larger display, when there are two completely visible items? I suspect you don't want two videos to auto play.

Comment: no, there is play only one video but in mobile showing two items,One is completely showing and another one is Part of portion showing